# How to return the view from controller in laravel in this case

Tags: php, laravel, api, model-view-controller

My question is how should I connect the things to return the view?
All of the time got an error like this:

MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251

Below you can check where I am:

web.php

```
Route::post('registered', 'AuthController@store_view')->name('registration.registered');
```

AuthController.php

```
public function store_view(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:5'
    ]);

    $name = $request->input('name');
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');

    $user = new User([
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => bcrypt($password)
    ]);

    if ($user->save()) {
        $user->signin = [
            'href' => 'api/v1/user/signin',
            'method' => 'POST',
            'params' => 'email, password'
        ];
        $response = [
            'msg' => 'User created',
            'user' => $user
        ];
        return view('registration.registered')->with('response',$response);
    }

    $response = [
        'msg' => 'An error occurred'
    ];

    return view('registration.registered')->with('response',$response);
}
```

register.blade.php

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:40px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <strong> Register to continue!</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form role="form" action="{{-- {{ url('/api/v1/user') }} --}}" method="POST">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <fieldset>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="center-block">
                                    <img class="profile-img"
                                        src="{{ URL::to('img/key.png') }}" alt="key">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10  col-md-offset-1 ">

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                                            </span> 
                                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="name" type="text" autofocus>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
                                            </span> 
                                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="text">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>
                                            </span>
                                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Register">
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer ">
                    Already have an account? <a href="{{route('sign.login')}}" onClick=""> Sign In Here! </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form use this, the form action attribute must be the name of you route:

```
<form role="form" action="{{route('registration.registered')}}"
```